# c++ stl containers:where can we use them

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

So we know that the basic structures which form the backbone of C++ algorithms are:

- trees set
- queue
- linkedlist
- array
- vector map
- unordered_map and pair.

My question is which data structure is suitable for which application.For instance I know that for Database indexing and searching preferred choices are B+ tree and Hash table.Can anyone shed some more light on this,

Comment: never mind,I found the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is way too broad. There are tons of situations where different data structures might be fit, and the only way to be able to figure out which structure to use is to learn about those data structures yourself and understand them. You can also look for info on sites like [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) about standard library containers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not only a C++ problem, but also an *algorithm* question. It maybe too broad, but I can give you some advice.

---

- `set` and `map`: They are ordered container, it is used for a **both manytimes-insert-and-read** structure. It can finish `insert` `delete` `read` in `O(logn)` time.
- `vector`: used for something like `dynamic array` or a structure you will frequently `push_back` at it, and if no other reason, you should use it.
- `deque`: much like `vector`, but it can also finish `push_front` in `O(1)` time
- `list`: used for a structure you need to frequently insert, but less *random access*
- `unordered_map` and `unordered_set`: look for `hash table`
- `array`: used for a structure whose size is fixed.
- `pair` and `tuple`: bind many object into one `struct`. Nothing special

Beside all of this, there are also some container meeting other requirement, you can serach them.
e.g. `any` and `optional`

Comment: thanks for answering it.But as I had already mentinoed,I did my own research later and was able to find the answer.So if anyone knows how to close it.Please feel free to do so.thanks